# Prove: if $f(z)$ differentiable in $|z|<R$ So Does $\overline {f(\overline{z})}$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Prove: if $f(z)$ differentiable in $|z|<R$  So Does  $\overline {f(\overline{z})}$

I have went over previous similar questions but did not find an answer to the following:

We say that $f(z)$ differentiable in $|z|<R$ therefore

$$u_x=v_y$$ and $$u_y=-v_x$$

Looking at $$\overline {f(\overline{z})}=U(x,-y)-iV(x,-y)$$

We can say that it is defined in $|z|<R$ as $|z|=|\overline{z}|<R$

But looking at its $C-R$ equations we get

$$U_x=--V_y\iff U_x=V_y\iff u_x=v_y$$

$$-U_y=-V_x\neq u_y=-v_x$$

How can we conclude from $C-R$ that $\overline {f(\overline{z})}$ is differentiable?

Comment: Aside from your abuse of notation, you should have $U_y = - V_x$, since we are looking at $- \frac{\partial U(x,-y)}{\partial y} = - - \frac{\partial U}{\partial y} = U_y$ (I'm also abusing notation; I hope you understand what I wrote)

Comment: @OpenBall Why do you have $--U_y$ and not $-U_y$?

Comment: Well I'm abusing notation, so it will be quite difficult for me to explain stuff. If you can write an intelligible outline of what you have to prove, I can point out to you what you should do.

Comment: @OpenBall Got it, Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f(z)=f(x+yi)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ is differentiable, so that all first-order partial derivatives of $f$ exist and satisfy $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$. Let $g(z) = \overline{f(\overline z)}$. Then $f(\overline z) = f(x-yi) = u(x,-y)+iv(x,-y)$, and so $g(z)=u(x,-y)-iv(x,-y)$ $=U(x,y)+iV(x,y)$. Since the map $z\mapsto \overline z$ is real-differentiable, $g$ is real differentiable, and further

$$U_x(x,y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} u(x,-y) = u_x(x,-y) = v_y(x,-y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(-v(x,-y)) = V_y(x,y)$$
$$U_y(x,y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}u(x,-y) = -u_y(x,-y) = v_x(x,-y) = -\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(-v(x,-y)) = V_x(x,y)$$

Answer (score 3):

If $f(z)$ is differentiable in $|z|<R$ (I guess, in the complex sense) then $f(z)$ can be written as a power series
$$ f(z) = a_0 + a_1 z + a_2 z^2 +\ldots $$
uniformly converging to $f(z)$ over any compact subset of $|z|<R$. If you replace $z$ with $\overline{z}$, then conjugate both sides, you get
$$ \overline{f(\overline{z})} = \overline{a_0} + \overline{a_1}z+\overline{a_2} z^2+\ldots $$
and that still is a power series in $z$ that is uniformly converging over any compact subset of $|z|<R$, since the radius of convergence is the same as the previous power series. In particular, $\overline{f(\overline{z})}$ is analytic, hence differentiable, in $|z|<R$.

Comment: Yes, this is answering it easily, I am trying to understand the answer via $C-R$

Comment: @gbox: the Cauchy-Riemann equations imply that any differentiable function in the complex sense is analytic by Cauchy's integral formula. You may simply prove this classical result, then apply the power series approach.

Comment: As a simple alternative, you may just show that "$f(z)$ fulfills the CR equations" implies "$\overline{f(\overline{z})}$ fulfills the CR equations as well" by simple algebraic manipulations.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I am trying to do

Comment: @gbox: then do it. $f(z)=f(a+bi)= R(a,b)+i I(a,b)$ with $R,I$ being real functions over $\mathbb{R}^2$. The CR equations tell you how $R$ and $I$ are connected, and $\overline{f(\overline{z})} = \overline{f(a-bi)} = R(a,-b)-i I(a,-b)$. To check the previous claim is now straightforward.

Comment: Got it, Thanks!